# RxJs pluck vs NgRx select

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I'm developing an Angular application with an NgRx store, and have a service that mediates between the view and the store. When I write a function to retrieve a piece of the store, I tend to use NgRx's `select` operator:

```
getSomeInfoFromStore(): Observable<SomeInfo> {
  return this.store.pipe(select('SomeInfo'));
  // --------------------^^^^^^
}
```

But I have also seen similar service functions written using RxJs's 'pluck' operator:

```
getSomeInfoFromStore(): Observable<SomeInfo> {
  return this.store.pipe(pluck('SomeInfo'));
  // --------------------^^^^^
}
```

What is the difference between [RxJs's `pluck` operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-pluck) and [NgRx's `select` operator](https://ngrx.io/api/store/select)? Are they interchangeable?  If not, when should I use each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example it does the same AFAIK.

The difference is that NgRx's `select` can make use of selectors, where the real power is.
By creating selectors with the `createSelector` method you gain a performance boost because it will only be invoked when the state changes.

https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors

Comment: Looks like the benefits extend beyond just performance; while more verbose, the selectors also provide a measure of type-safety not really available when using the string inputs.  Thanks!